# Set list entry limit in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am creating a sign up sheet for students to register for some information sessions using Sharepoint 2010.  The problem is that each session has a different max capacity.  I am currently using radio buttons for the student's selections.  Is there any way to set a capacity for different columns in the list?

Comment: each session time slot has 3 choices.  The students choose which info session they want to attend for each time slot.